# Spring Kafka Manual Ack and retry happens after exception : unexpected behaviour

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka consumer annotated with @KakaListner, with in consumer i have requirement like to acknowledge kafka message first and then execute rest api. So while executing rest api i am getting exception which is expected behaviour and consumer reties happening even i ack. same message before rest call.

```
     @KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.kafka.topic.name}", groupId = "${consumer.topicGroupId}")
        public void listenEvent(ConsumerRecord<String, Event> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) throws IOException {

             acknowledgment.acknowledge();
             patchService.patch(arguments...);
}
```

PatchService code :

```
    public class PatchService {

         public String patch(arguments....) {

       try {
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.PATCH, request, String.class);
            return response.getBody();
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
            log.error("Error updating API having error response {}", ex.getResponseBodyAsString());
            throw new APIException(ex.getStatusCode(), ex.getResponseBodyAsString());
        }

     }
}
```

ConsumerConfiguration Code :

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() throws FileNotFoundException {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    return factory;
}
```

With this property set to false in consumerFactory() :

props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");

What i am doing wrong here ? i don't want retries when exception comes as part of rest api i just want to log that message which i am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the exception and don't throw it.

Kafka maintains two pointers for each group/partition - the current position and the committed offset.

The default error handler resets the current position so the failed record will be redelivered, regardless of the committed offset.

Comment: PatchService is used in Sync flows as well in Async flow means it's also used some where apart from kafka consumer where i am handling APIException in Global Exception Handler to make custom error response and sending back to calling source. Any other alternative apart from not throwing exception ?

Comment: Configure the error handler so that it never retries and immediately recovers the failed record (the default recoverer just logs it). If necessary, you can determine the behavior based on the exception type. See `addNotRetryableExceptions`.

Comment: Configure the error handler so that it never retries : This i explored and i see SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(BackOff backOff) method in which i can give backoff policy, is there any other option to achieve this ? Immediately recovers the failed record (the default recoverer just logs it) : can you explain more or help in sample.

Comment: What version are you using? The `STCEH` has been replaced by the `DefaultErrorHandler` in currently supported versions. I still don't see why you can't catch the exception in `listenEvent()`.

Comment: Spring-kafka : 2.7.9 and i tried catching APIException and not throwing in listenEvent method of consumer but retry problem still exists. Added error handler in container factory : private SeekToCurrentErrorHandler getErrorHandler() {
        return new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(0L, 0L));
    }

Comment: It doesn't make any sense that catching and not re throwing the exception would cause the record to be redelivered. The container will never redeliver a record if no exception is thrown.